# How can I get a published page url having a component using odata service api?

Tags: service, odata

I am using odata service to query broker database. I want to get the page detail which is created from a given component.

I have a list of components and for each component I want to fetch all the pages published which are using that component.

I can get the link of page through the Component ID using the Broker API method of `GetLink` available in the `ComponentLink` class of `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking`.

Can anyone suggest how can I get the links of pages relevant to this Component using the ODATA service?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Is your page published from the CMS? is your component published dynamically?  Finally, have you tried hitting the Odata webservice via the browser and see what entities are available?

Comment: @user2781215: have you already been able to retrieve a the relevant Component through OData? If so, you can normally get to the Pages quite easily by adding `/Page` (or `/Pages`) to the end of the URL. If you show your current code, it'll be easier for people to show where you need to head next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another webservice for linking: /linking.svc. Its mentioned in the [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=linking.svc&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1380101772212&currentQuery=linking.svc&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_277A2D7264B04A39870C3FE18EF245BB&query=linking.svc&scope=&filename=CDWSLinkingAPI.xml&docid=reference_277A2D7264B04A39870C3FE18EF245BB&inner_id=&tid=835c957f-b518-43c9-9c32-8abc92a48745&addHistory=true&resource=) [login required], heres an example URL (.NET):

```
http://mywebservice/linking.svc/componentLink?sourcePageURI=tcm:1-50-64&targetComponentURI=tcm:1-55-16&excludeTemplateURI=tcm:0-0-0&linkText=MyLink
```